# decodeByteArray(data[0] returns null PictureCallback

Tags: android

I have the following callback

```
    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            new processImage().execute(data);
        }
    };
```

And the task is this, the bmp here is always null, any ideas?

```
private class processImage extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(byte[]... data) {


        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data[0], 0, data.length);

        //Do stuff with the bmp    


    }
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you do not call correctly the `decodeByteArray` function. It should be `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data[0],0,data[0].length)`

Comment: Actually `data` is a varargs parameter so `data[0]` is the first `byte[]`. The last parameter should probably be `data[0].length`.

Comment: You are correct, the mistake is when the length is given, should be data[0].length, I didn't see the varargs parameter, sorry.

Comment: I just found the issue as well, you're right, it's the data[0].length.

Comment: No problem. Might as well edit the answer to fix it so @AdroidFreak can accept it.